# mysqldump very slow

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, virtualisation

We have an application running on mysql 5.1.73. We recently converted the server from physical to virtual and from that date the mysqldump is running for a very long time.
We have a big database of 300Gb and it used to completed within 6 hours previously;  but after P2V the backups are running for a very long time.
Please advise if we need to take any additional steps a mysql end after converting the underlying hardware to virtual.

Answer (score 1):

@ajith, you haven't mentioned storage engine in picture. But since version is 5.1.x, i presume it to be moreover to MyISAM or with few InnoDB tables. Following possible solutions suit your environment

1. Physical backup (LVM snapshots) - [mylvmbackup](https://www.lenzg.net/mylvmbackup/)
   This should be lot faster than running mysqldump with 300GB data with minimum overhead to running system.
2. Hot backup - [Percona xtrabackup](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/index.html)
   This is another solution giving way more flexibility in terms of resource configuration for backup/compress/stream at same time it features to monitor and threshold backup process to not over-utilize resources.

Since MySQL 5.1 is very old, try to check for any limitations/bugs that may affect your version. It is advisable to use separate storage for backup than datadir.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case the issue seems to be related to disk speed.

My physical server was running in SSD and once we performed the P2V the disks from storage was only SAS.

Mysql configuration in my environment seems to be not compatable with SAS disks; it require SSD disks.

After migrating the VM from SAS to SSD all issues seems to be resolved.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Sure @ajith Throwing better hardware resolves issues most of the time. But you can still consider the better backup approaches for large data-sets.